# android - Search isn't repopulating results / list after backspacing

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, searchview

I am attempting to take the Searchview function of this:
github.com/Wrdlbrnft/Searchable-RecyclerView-Demo (can't post more than 2 links, sorry)

- [.GIF of original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqNER.gif)

I have attempted to add it to a project. However, when I do so, my results get filtered, but do not get added back when a user revises or backspaces.

- [.GIF of mine not functioning correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJRHZ.gif)

The code is near identical. I didn't change anything with the adapter.

**CustomAdapter.java**
    public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
// Dataset = list of players and their attributes
private final ArrayList<PlayerData> dataSet;
private final List<PlayerData> filteredList;
private ArrayList<PlayerData> originalItems;
public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView textViewName;
    TextView textViewPos;
    ImageView imageViewFace;
    ImageView imageTeamLogo;
    TextView textViewTeam;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.textViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        this.textViewPos = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPos);
        this.imageViewFace = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewFace);
        this.imageTeamLogo = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ImgTeamLogo);
        this.textViewTeam = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTeam);

    }
}
//dataset = data from Main Activity
public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<PlayerData> data) {
    this.dataSet = data;
    this.filteredList = data;

}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                       int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.cards_layout, parent, false);

    MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);

    return myViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int Position) {
    // called everytime user scrolls up or down
    TextView textViewName = holder.textViewName;
    TextView textViewPos = holder.textViewPos;
    ImageView imageViewFace = holder.imageViewFace;
    ImageView imageViewLogo = holder.imageTeamLogo;
    TextView textViewTeam = holder.textViewTeam;


    textViewName.setText(dataSet.get(Position).getName());

    textViewPos.setText(dataSet.get(Position).getPos());

    textViewTeam.setText(dataSet.get(Position).getTeam());




    Context context = imageViewFace.getContext();
    Context context2 = imageViewLogo.getContext();

    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(dataSet.get(Position).getFace())
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .error(R.drawable.ic_3d_rotation)
            .into(holder.imageViewFace);

    Glide.with(context2).load(dataSet.get(Position).getTeamLogo()).into(holder.imageTeamLogo);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataSet.size();
}
public void animateTo(ArrayList<PlayerData> players) {
    //checks what query found and adds / removes results
    // problem is, it is not adding back results
    applyAndAnimateRemovals(players);
    applyAndAnimateAdditions(players);
    applyAndAnimateMovedItems(players);

}

private void applyAndAnimateRemovals(ArrayList<PlayerData> newPlayers) {
    for (int i = dataSet.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        final PlayerData player = dataSet.get(i);
        if (!newPlayers.contains(player)) {
            removeItem(i);
        }
    }
}

private void applyAndAnimateAdditions(ArrayList<PlayerData> newPlayers) {
    for (int i = 0, count = newPlayers.size(); i < count; i++) {
        final PlayerData player = newPlayers.get(i);
        if (!dataSet.contains(player)) {
            addItem(i, player);
        }
    }
}


private void applyAndAnimateMovedItems(ArrayList<PlayerData> newPlayers) {
    for (int toPosition = newPlayers.size() - 1; toPosition >= 0; toPosition--) {
        final PlayerData player = newPlayers.get(toPosition);
        final int fromPosition = dataSet.indexOf(player);
        if (fromPosition >= 0 && fromPosition != toPosition) {
            moveItem(fromPosition, toPosition);
        }
    }
}

public PlayerData removeItem(int position) {
        final PlayerData player = dataSet.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);

        return player;
    }
    public void addItem(int position, PlayerData player) {
        dataSet.add(position, player);
        // this code is not working for whatever reason)
        notifyItemInserted(position);


    }

    public void moveItem(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
        final PlayerData player = dataSet.remove(fromPosition);
        dataSet.add(toPosition, player);
        notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{

private static RecyclerView recyclerView;
private static CustomAdapter adapter;
private static ArrayList<PlayerData> data;





private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    data = new ArrayList<PlayerData>();


    addPlayers();
    adapter = new CustomAdapter(data);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


}


public interface Constants {
    String LOG = "com.vogella.testapp";
}
private void addPlayers() {

    PlayerData player = new PlayerData("Chris Smith", "#", R.drawable.auser, R.drawable.aquestion, "First", 0);
    data.add(0,player);
    player = new PlayerData("Bobby Richars","#", R.drawable.auser, R.drawable.aquestion, "Second", 9);
            data.add(player);
    player = new PlayerData("Steven Williams", "#", R.drawable.auser, R.drawable.aquestion, "Third", 1);
    data.add(player);


    player = new PlayerData("Tony Lloyd", "#", R.drawable.auser, R.drawable.aquestion, "Fourth", 2);
    data.add(player);

    player = new PlayerData("Henry Gates", "#", R.drawable.auser,R.drawable.aquestion, "Fifth", 3);
    data.add(player);

    player = new PlayerData("Robert Marks", "#", R.drawable.auser, R.drawable.aquestion, "Sixth", 4);
    data.add(player);


    player = new PlayerData("Edward Jackson", "#", R.drawable.auser, R.drawable.aquestion, "SEVENTH", 5);
    data.add(player);

    player = new PlayerData("Zack Jordan", "#", R.drawable.auser, R.drawable.aquestion, "Eighth", 6);
    data.add(player);

    player = new PlayerData("Christopher Thomas", "#", R.drawable.auser, R.drawable.aquestion, "Ninth", 7);
    data.add(player);

    player = new PlayerData("Bruce Allen", "#", R.drawable.auser, R.drawable.aquestion, "Tenth", 8);
    data.add(player);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    return true;

}
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
    final ArrayList<PlayerData> filteredModelList = filter(data, query);
    adapter.animateTo(filteredModelList);
    recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return false;
}

private ArrayList<PlayerData> filter(ArrayList<PlayerData> players, String query) {
    query = query.toLowerCase();

    final ArrayList<PlayerData> filteredModelList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (PlayerData player : players) {
        final String text = player.getName().toLowerCase() + player.getPos().toLowerCase()+ player.getTeam().toLowerCase();
        if (text.contains(query)) {
            filteredModelList.add(player);
        }
    }
    return filteredModelList;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was a small error.

**Custom Adapter**

```
public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<PlayerData> data) {
this.dataSet = data;
this.filteredList = data;
```

}

into

```
public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<PlayerData> data) {
    this.dataSet = new ArrayList<>(data);
```

Just removed that and it works.